# about boost.asio async sleep

Tags: c++, boost-asio

I use `boost.asio` async read data, if `handle_read` takes a lot of time (such as sleep), does it affect other connections?

Comment: your question is not clear to me, please clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you execute `io_service::run` in one thread, the completion handlers of all the i/o objects associated with that `io_service` are invoked sequentially. So, if one of them takes too much time, all the queue gets stuck.

To prevent this situation, you can either re-design this completion handler, or associate the i/o object having problematic handlers with its own dedicated `io_service` running in a separate thread.

(Note that running a single `io_serivce` in multiple threads wouldn't solve this problem, as you can't know how the handlers are distributed among the threads.)

Answer (score 2):

With async IO, you usually do everything in one thread, so you should try to keep things as short as possible. You *definitely don't* want to sleep while handling input.

Boost has [timers](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/doc/html/boost_asio/tutorial/tuttimer2.html) to let you do an asynchronous sleep.